# Spark in Oozie Workflow throws Class not found Exception

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, hue

[image: [Hue Workflow with Argument]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHA7G.png)

Hue 3.10
Spark 1.6.0
CDH 5.8.0

When i run jar using spark-submit command it works fine but using hue workflow it gives me an error.

> `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RowCountFilter
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:175)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.runSpark(SparkMain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:207)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:49)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:52)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:236)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
>   Intercepting System.exit(101)
>   Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [101]

`

>
Can anyone help what is missing ?

Comment: Seems the Spark action cannot find the jar file. Could also be that the name of the class is not correct. I'm not 100% certain but it could be that the Spark action by default assumes the jar to be in HDFS if you do not add `file://` or something.

Comment: My Jars is in **HDFS** and Class name is also Correct. and i also tried with that 'hdfs://' but it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried adding the package name to the class name? E.g. `my.package.RowCountFilter`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. @LiMuBei , I just make sample code so no package is added in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your job.properties & coordinator.properties file. check the lib path `oozie.libpath` in these files and see if the required jar is present.

When oozie triggers a job , it will check the jars in the lib path  distribute the  to all the nodes in the cluster for execution.

You may also want to verify the configs in oozie-site.xml